# Javascript Array Sorting issue

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a program that basically allows a viewer to enter an employees name, and their salary, and then hit a confirmation button. When this button is hit, a table row and cell is added for both the salary and employee name in a table below. Now, the results are also sorted by alphabetical order. However, the issue is that the results aren't sorted until after the display of the createbody function. So, the alphabetical order isn't updated until after a new employee is entered. My goal is to have the results sort in real-time, **OR have a separate button that will sort the results**. Either way is fine. code is listed below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<title> Table Entry </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input type="text" id="fullName" value="" placeholder="Firstname"> :Enter employee name <br> 
<input type="text" id="salary" value="" placeholder="Salary"> :Enter employee salary <br> 
<input type="button" value="click me add to employee list" onclick="addToArray()"> <p>&nbsp;</p> 
<input type="button" value="click me to sort employees" onclick="sortEm()"> <p>&nbsp;</p> 
<div id="tablediv">
<table border="1" id="source" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"> 
 <thead> 
  <tr> <th>Employee Name</th> <th>Employee Salary</th> </tr> 
 </thead> 
 <tbody id="sourceBody"> 
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
 </tbody> 
</table> </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function sortEm() {
var tbl = document.getElementById('source');
var row = tbl.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
row.deleteCell(0);
document.getElementById("tbl").deleteRow(1);


}
var NameSalaries= []; 
function addToArray() { 
  var fn = document.getElementById('fullName').value; 
  var sly = document.getElementById('salary').value; 
  var both = [fn,sly]; 
  NameSalaries.push(both); 
  createBody(NameSalaries); 
  document.getElementById('fullName').focus(); 
  NameSalaries.sort();
  } 

function createBody(NS) { 
  var tarr = []; 
  for (var i=0; i<NS.length; i++) { 
    tarr.push('<tr><td>'+NS[i][0]+'</td><td>'+NS[i][1]+'</td></tr>');  
  } document.getElementById('sourceBody').innerHTML = tarr.join(''); 
} 



</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's fair to state that one way is unequivocally better than the other as they both have pluses and minuses.

### Sort by button

+ More sense of control by user.  Interface lends itself to the idea that nothing is performed until you click on a button that tells your application to do it.  Some clients prefer this type of interface (usually older clients).

+ No extra work being done behind the scenes, so you maintain maximum responsiveness from your application.  May not be a big deal in this case, but it is worth mentioning.

- Less intuitive.  Adding more functionality always adds complexity.  Sometimes the functionality is worth the complexity, and sometimes it is not.  Seeing how there is another way to do this, I would argue the latter.

### Realtime sort

+ Interface is consistent. If the user indicated a specific ordering and you allowed a breach in that ordering, while acceptable, users still notice, and it is like a blaring plothole in your film.  Sometimes it is just better to not compromise the interface.

- Unexpected delays.  Should you ever need to update the list in moments other than those where the user explicitly asked for an action to be performed, sorting will likely be required and thus will create a tiny delay.  This delay will obviously increase as the number of items in your list increase.

- Inserted employee must be found again in your list.  This can technically have a workaround if you're willing to do a little work and jump to the point in the list where the employee has been added.  This is more relevant if you're using pagination.

- Adds complexity in your program.  Contrary to the sort by button point of being less intuitive, typically more intuitive client interfaces require more complexity making it all work behind the scenes.

### Conclusion

If I can make a suggestion, I think you should have table column headers that sort only when clicked.  The lines will be sorted according to the column that was clicked, and clicking a second time will just reverse the ordering (tip: you won't need to sort it again for that).

When you add a new employee, simply resort with current ordering.  If nothing else, your client is less likely to complain that you simply maintained ordering as opposed to added the employee to the end of the list.

If you think you might be dealing with very large lists, consider using a webworker to perform the sort to avoid delays on the page.  If you're using an insert sort, you could return the results live as the webworker is sorting, and on your page, you simply recreate the rows.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Based on the information you've provided and a little bit of thinking, I think sorting by button would be more effective. Have any tips on how I could achieve that?

Comment: What?  The sort or the sort button?

Comment: Just the button. Sorry.

Comment: @Suplexx Add an onclick attribute to the button that calls a function that sorts your list.  Alternatively, you could add onclick to the table header and sort according to the column type.